# SWT: get number of characters that are about to be deleted from Text widget

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I am validating inputs from some SWT Text widgets.
Assume a user selects some portion of the text he himself inserted into the widget by using the mouse or `Ctrl. + A` etc. and then presses delete; how do I get the number of characters that are about to be deleted? I am using a SWT verify event for the input validation. The documentation says that event.text will give "the new text that will be inserted.[...]" and has the ability to modify the text that will be deleted, but I am unable to find a way to just get the amount of text that will be deleted.

Google didn't give me the answer either. Has anybody a idea how to achieve this?

As the actual code is rather lengthy, I had to cut the unnecessary parts for posting it here:

The purpose of the code is to take 32 Hexadecimal digits and allowing Copy/Paste.

```
int len = 0;
// input is a SWT Text widget with initial text set to ""
input.addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener() {
    public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e){
        e.doit = false;
        int addit = 0;
        // do nothing when there are already 32 characters in the widget
        if (len == 32){
            return;
        }
        // allow Ctrl + v to paste
        if(((e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) == SWT.CTRL) && (e.keyCode == 'v') && (len + e.text.length()) <= 32){
            e.doit = true;
            // here it works like a charm
            addit = e.text.length();
        }
        // allow deleting characters: Problem: deleting multiple characters at a time
        if (e.keyCode == SWT.BS || e.keyCode == SWT.DEL){
            e.doit = true;
            addit = ???;    // this is the problem: how many characters are deleted, when the key is pressed
        }
        // isHex is a function that checks, weather e.character is a hexadecimal digit
        if (isHex(e.character) || Character.isDigit(e.character) && len+1 <= 32){
            e.doit = true;
            addit = 1;
        } else if (e.keyCode != SWT.BS && e.keyCode != SWT.BS && ((e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) != SWT.CTRL) && e.keyCode != 'v') {
            System.out.println(e.character + " is not valid");
            return;
        }
        len += addit;
        if (len == 32){
            somemethod();
        }
        // print how many characters are there the moment the user types or deletes them
        System.out.println((32 - len) + "chars");
    }});
}
```

Comment: post your code please !! we have to see the code to see where is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply compare the length of the original text and the user modification after the verify event. Listen to  `SWT.Verify` and compare the length:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    text.addListener(SWT.Verify, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            final String oldS = text.getText();
            final String newS = oldS.substring(0, e.start) + e.text + oldS.substring(e.end);

            int difference = oldS.length() - newS.length();

            if(difference > 0)
                System.out.println("User deleted " + difference + " characters");
            else if(difference < 0)
                System.out.println("User added " + Math.abs(difference) + " characters");
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: thank you, works like a charm; sorry unable to upvote the answer due to low reputation.

Comment: @user3802900 You're welcome. Don't worry about the upvote. You'll eventually get enough reputation to upvote others.